# How to Generate LinkedHashMap in the form of table that has been generated dynamically using itext7

Tags: java, itext7, linkedhashmap

[image: This is the output table]This is the code for dynamic table generation. Can any one help to convert this table data into `LinkedHashMap` table format.

Please give me some idea to merge the table in LinkedHashMap.

```
    Table content = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{5,5,5}));
    content.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Cell[] headerFooter = new Cell[] {
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("#")),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("Key")),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("Value"))
        };
        for (Cell hfCell : headerFooter) {
            if (i == 0) {
                content.addHeaderCell(hfCell);
            } else {
                //content.addFooterCell(hfCell);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int counter = 1; counter <4; counter++){

        Cell[] contentTable = new Cell[]{
                new Cell(2,2).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(counter))).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("key " + counter)),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("value " + counter))

        };


        for (Cell tabCell : contentTable){                              
            if(counter % 2 == 0){                   
                tabCell.setBackgroundColor(DeviceGray.WHITE);
            }else {                 
                tabCell.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.75f));  
            }

            content.addFooterCell(tabCell);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"`LinkedHashMap` table format"*?

Comment: You mean converting `contentTable` in a LinkedHashMap? What would be the keys?

Comment: @Bsquare - You are correct ., the keys would be `"key" + counter and "value" + counter `.

Comment: Ok. But those are fixed strings. So you can simply create a map and put those three key-value pairs into it. This surely cannot be what you want, can it?

Comment: yeah your right., that is my query how to do dynamically using `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Ok, you want that instead of your existing Table, OR you want a convert system from the existing Table, to a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: I need to convert to LinkedHashMap, Finally I done.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer to your needs, like I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is the output that I searched.Thanks for your support everyone :)

```
        LinkedHashMap<String, Cell> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for(int counter = 1; counter <4; counter++){


            Cell[] contentTable = new Cell[]{
                    new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(counter))).setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY),
                    new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("key " + counter)),
                    new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("value " + counter))

            };

            for (Cell tabCell : contentTable){  
                hash.put("key",tabCell);
                if(counter % 2 == 0){                   
                    tabCell.setBackgroundColor(DeviceGray.WHITE);
                }else {                 
                    tabCell.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.75f));  
                }

                content.addFooterCell(hash.get("key"));

            }

        }
```

Comment: ??? What do you need the map for here? It only contains a single value, the current `Cell` which you also can access as `tabCell`. ..

Answer (score 0):

I done it. But this will work to add data statically in the table using `LinkedHashMap`.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> hash = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // put values in hashmap
    hash.put("key1", "value1");
    hash.put("key2", "value2");
    hash.put("key3", "value3");

    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{5,5,5}));
    table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));

    table.addCell(hash.get("key1"));
    table.addCell(hash.get("key2"));
    table.addCell(hash.get("key3"));

    Cell[] headerFooter = new Cell[] {
            new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("#")),
            new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("Key")),
            new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("Value"))
    };
    for (Cell hfCell : headerFooter) {

        table.addHeaderCell(hfCell);

    }
    doc.add(table);
```

Comment: i need how to add these data dynamically , can any one tell me how to do?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not perfectly crystal clear, but according to your partial answers, I guess the answer you are looking is that:

```
public void enhanceHashMapWithTable() {
    Table content = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] { 5, 5, 5 }));
    Map<String, Cell> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++) {
        Cell[] contentTable = new Cell[] {
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(counter)))
                        .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("key " + counter)),
                new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph("value " + counter))

        };

        for (Cell tabCell : contentTable) {
            hash.put("key " + counter, tabCell);
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                tabCell.setBackgroundColor(DeviceGray.WHITE);
            } else {
                tabCell.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceGray(0.75f));
            }

            content.addFooterCell(hash.get("key " + counter));
        }

    }
}
```

In this case, your key will be dynamically created, and different/coherent for each of your cell.

Comment: @Yahini On Stackoverflow you can give [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to people's helpful answers to thank them.